# Preventing orphaned users in SQL Server 2008 R2

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2, users, logins

I've recently had a situation where a database was refreshed from production to staging, and the users on the database ended up orphaned.

- These are sql server users, not mapped to windows credentials.
- The database users use the same credentials on both PRD and STG.
- The database users are called the same on both PRD and STG.
- The SQL Server logins are called the same on both PRD and STG.
- The database was refreshed by using a `RESTORE` with `REPLACE` and `MOVE` to rename the data files.

As I understand it, this is because the SID's of the logins don't match between our two environments.

How could I make it so that the SID's of the sql server logins on our staging environment are the same as on our production environment going forward?

My thought is to use `CREATE LOGIN WITH SID ='SID value from PRD'` but this has the disadvantages of needing to drop the logins first, and I'm not entirely sure that manually defining an SID is healthy / wise.

Maybe there is a way to have the logins migrated with the backup? (if [sp_help_revlogin](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/918992) has been available to manually copy logins, why don't backups have this option)

Comment: I know the question is for SQL 2008 but if you ever consider SQL 2014 take a look at a feature called contained databases.

Answer (score 3):

> As I understand it, this is because the SID's of the logins don't
>   match between our two environments.

You understand correctly!

> How could I make it so that the SID's of the sql server logins on our
>   staging environment are the same as on our production environment
>   going forward? My thought is to use CREATE LOGIN WITH SID ='SID value
>   from PRD' but this has the disadvantages of needing to drop the logins
>   first, and I'm not entirely sure that manually defining an SID is
>   healthy / wise.

If the logins are already created, you'll have to drop them anyway - so that's a moot point. You can use the SSIS migrate logins task, sp_helprevlogin, CREATE LOGIN WITH SID =, and lastly you can make the database partially contained.

> Maybe there is a way to have the logins migrated with the backup? (if
>   sp_help_revlogin has been available to manually copy logins, why don't
>   backups have this option)

Logins are a server scoped principal and can have a 1 to many relationship with users. Thus it doesn't make sense to include a server scope item with a database scoped item, that's why users exist. What you're looking for is called partially contained databases, which let a special type of user exist which has a passed and can be used like a login though it lives in the database and not at the server level. It's only good for that database and there are some requirements.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff929071.aspx